# Stop click from firing on sub items

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have html that looks like this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="database">Item One
        <ul>
            <li>Sub One</li>
            <li>Sub Two</li>
            <li>Sub Three</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="database">Item Two
        <ul>
            <li>Sub One</li>
            <li>Sub Two</li>
            <li>Sub Three</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
<ul>
```

I then created this JavaScript to hide/show the sub list when clicked.

```
$(document).on('click', 'li.database', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).children('ul').children('li').toggle();
});
```

It works, but it hides the list no matter if I click on the submenu or not. How can I hide the items only when the root `li` is clicked? I would like to eventually have the sub items have their own events when clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check to see if [`e.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) is the same as [`e.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget).

This works because [`e.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) is the element that fired the event, and [`e.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) is the element that the event listener is attached to.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/a8fmsatx/)

```
$(document).on('click', 'li.database', function (e) {
  if (e.target === e.currentTarget) {
    $(this).children('ul').children('li').toggle();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Check which `target` was clicked. `e.target`.

Use `e.stopPropagation()` in the click events for the sub-items instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an id tag and reference that rather than the class name. That way you can separate the databases by id.